# Pip install Soundcloud issue on Windows despite pip, setuptools are up to date

Tags: python, soundcloud

I am working on a Windows computer on which I would like to install the soundcloud library.

My current setup:

```
C:\Users\gmeun\Desktop\ProjetsPython\soundcloud>pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
ez-setup   0.9
pip        23.2.1
setuptools 68.0.0
wheel      0.41.0
```

My Python version:

```
C:\Users\gmeun\Desktop\ProjetsPython\soundcloud>python
Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

When I try to install the soundcloud package I got:

```
C:\Users\gmeun\Desktop\ProjetsPython\soundcloud>pip install soundcloud
Collecting soundcloud
  Using cached soundcloud-0.5.0.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting fudge>=1.0.3 (from soundcloud)
  Using cached fudge-1.1.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in fudge setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

The `python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully` seems to be due to a potential out dated pip or setuptools or ez-setup not installed; so I tried to update everyting but I am already pointing to the last versions available...

As Fudge seems to be also used, I tried to pip install fudge and I got the same `python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully` error...

```
C:\Users\gmeun\Desktop\ProjetsPython\soundcloud>pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\gmeun\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (23.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\gmeun\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-packages (68.0.0)
```

and when I try to upgrade fudge:

```
C:\Users\gmeun\Desktop\ProjetsPython\soundcloud>pip install --upgrade fudge
Collecting fudge
  Using cached fudge-1.1.1.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in fudge setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

what is wrong with my setup? FYI, I am not using any VM nor virtual env

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. After downgrading to 57.4.0, it worked fine.

Try it out:

`pip install --upgrade setuptools==57.4.0`

`pip install soundcloud`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

it seems you got some compatibility issues with your python version and soundcloud package.
try upgrading pip, setuptools and fudge then install souncloud again

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
pip install --upgrade fudge
pip install soundcloud
```

hope it helps

Comment: Prior posting this request I tried your suggested commands to upgrade everything but still not working

Comment: Did you try clearing the pip cache ?  'pip cache purge'